# Realm wrong data in background fetch

Tags: swift, realm

I run the exact Same query

it returns zero when the app is on the foreground and else 24 ????. the correct value is zero.
the realm is running on autorefresh... still the same result is I relaunch the app

```
let realm =  try! Realm()
let predicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "hasChanged == true") ==> optional
let predicateDeleted = NSPredicate(format: "isDeleted == false")
let predicate2 = NSPredicate(format: "externalCode != nil AND externalCode != ''")
// let predicate3 = NSPredicate(format: "partner.partnerID = \(partner.partnerID)")
//predicate3,
let predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [predicate1,predicate2, predicateDeleted])


let tickets = realm.objects(Ticket.self).filter(predicate)

return tickets
```

Answer (score -1):

Found the mystery. due to the magic of threading, another one was modifying my realm in the background in a part of the code i didn't know. so quiet on the contrary realm works like a charm